# Updating multiple rows at once in Flask-SQLAlchemy Error: AttributeError: 'InstanceState' object has no attribute '_post_inspect'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to update multiple rows in using Flask SQLAlchemy with user inputted data. I am querying the Unique_Key to choose which row to edit. The three columns I'm trying to edit is: `Content, Link and Price` but everytime I try to update the row I get the same error:

> AttributeError: 'InstanceState' object has no attribute '_post_inspect'

My code is below, any help is much appreciated, I'm also a novice coder so I apoligise for my terrible code.

**DB Model**

```py
class wl(db.Model):
    username_wl = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    link = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

**Update Route**

```py
@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Update(id):
    item = wl.query.get_or_404(id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.form.get('content')
        link = request.form.get('link')
        price = request.form.get('price')

        db.session.query(item).update(values={'price': price}) # Where the error is occuring
        db.session.query(item).update(values={'content': content})
        db.session.query(item).update(values={'link': link})
#
        db.session.commit() 
        return redirect('/index')

    else:   
        return render_template('/update.html', item=item)
```

**HTML**

```html
<form action="/update/{{item.id}}" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="content" id="content" value="{{item.content}}" placeholder="Item Name">
            <input type="text" name="link" id="link" value="{{item.link}}" placeholder="Link">
            <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="{{item.price}}" placeholder="Price">
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Juul, "item = wl.query.get_or_404(id)", what  is "wl" representing in that line of code? are you selecting the rows you want to update in that line?

Comment: Hi wl is the name of the database I am using, I am querying my database for a unique key for a row and selecting that row, cheers for answering!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly, you are selecting all items that you want to update in this line of code:

```
item = wl.query.get_or_404(id)
```

So `item` is a `list` of model objects. But the `update()` method is an attribute of the sqlalchemy Query object. Updating rows can be done as follows, whereas Item is your `db.model` class:

```
@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Update(id):
    item = Item.query.filter(Item.id == id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.form.get('content')
        link = request.form.get('link')
        price = request.form.get('price')

        item.update(values={'price': price, 'content': content, 'link': link})

        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/index')
    else:   
        return render_template('/update.html', item=item.all())
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and now I'm getting the error: AttributeError: 'wl' object has no attribute 'update' On the item.update line

Comment: Could you provide the code, wherevyou defined your model?